# Data access layer by file implementation in spring

Tags: java, spring, data-access-layer, dao

I defined a `Data Access Layer` for my application `CRUD` operations and its interfaces. I want temporary save/load data to/from file but finally I will define appropriate model in relational database. So I wrote a file implementation of defined `DAO` layer for temporary.

My question is:

Is there a wrapper such as `JpaTemplate` for file `DAO` implementation in `Spring`?

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am still learning the English language.)

Comment: Sorry i am not able to understand your question. Can you inform us, what exactly you did so far? and what you are looking for?

Comment: You'll lose more time persisting and loading objects to and from file than setting up the database. I would do it ASAP, and forget about files. The semantics of the DAL will vary anyway: JPA entities are persisted automatically, without any need to call an `update()` method. Objects persisted to files won't be saved automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general file-based template.

Depending on the specific format you use, though, you may find tools that can help (even though they aren't templates). For example, you can use JAXB for XML and Jackson for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

No, to my knowlege, there ins no support by Spring provided Form file based DAOs.